# Find image coords in pdf with itext7 in core3

Tags: c#, pdf, matrix, itext7

I am trying to extract the x,y,width,height of image in a sertain pdf with itext 7.

whene i getting the matrix :

ImageRenderInfo renderInfo = (ImageRenderInfo)data;
Matrix ctm = renderInfo.GetImageCtm();

i have a certain image that its matrics looks like this:

"[95.25  -27.31  0 33.3  116  0  132.4  249.8]"

exctructing the coord from it:

float imageWidth = ctm.Get(0);
float imageHeight = ctm.Get(4);

float x = ctm.Get(Matrix.I31);
float y = ctm.Get(Matrix.I32);

gives me the wrong position -
[(look at the black frame of the attached image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqxW7.png)

How do i get the frame to be in its place, how to calculate to get the right result?

**UPDATE**: This image has been rotated

Comment: The CTM you post, `[95.25 -27.31 0 33.3 116 0 132.4 249.8]`, looks weird, having 8 entries. But if it is somewhat correct, the entries indicate a rotated image. Thus, your simple taking a single matrix value to determine width or height is wrong.

Comment: @mkl - You are absolutely right. This image has a rotation. So how do i come out from this situation, how can i find the borders of the image as i see it in the pdf?

Comment: *"how can i find the borders of the image as i see it in the pdf?"* - simply apply the ctm to the corners of the unit square - (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), and (0, 1, 1) - and you get the corners of the image on the page.

Comment: @mkl - didnt fully understood, can you pls write it as a calculation? multiply the ctm by 1x3 vector for each point?

Comment: *"multiply the ctm by 1x3 vector for each point"* - right, for each point **p** from the four points above calculate **p** × **CTM**. As a result you get the coordinates of the four corners of the parallelogram in the user space in which the image is drawn.

Comment: after the calculation i get a rotaited rectangle, not straight as in the pdf. the points are: [165, 365.8], [132.4, 249], [227.65, 222.49], [260, 338]

Comment: *"after the calculation i get a rotaited rectangle"* - yes, obviously. *"not straight as in the pdf"* - I would assume that that *straight* photo you see actually has been scanned with a tilt on some white background, and that scan has been rotated a bit to counter that tilt when it was added to your pdf. If that's not the case, please share the PDF for analysis.